# Solving $a^2-3a+2<0$.

Tags: inequality

Okay. I am confused in this part. 
$$(a-1)(a-2)<0$$ $$a<1;a<2$$ So $$a\in(-\infty,1)$$. But the answer is $$a\in(1,2)$$ How please help? 
Edit: I still cannot understand why we take the latter to be the correct answer. But if I ask you what will be the solutions of $$(a-1)(a-2)(a-4)<0$$ then? 
Edit: Okay, I understood. Because the product of the two numbers is negative! But how will you solve the previous $3$ term inequality?

Comment: The product is negative if exactly one of them is negative. Consider both cases

Comment: @Aditya Agarwal. Your though process for solving these inequalities is wrong, see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the algebraic sign of $(a-1)(a-2)$ for different values of $a$, remembering how the sign of the product of two numbers behaves:

```
       a-1:       -         0      +     +         +  
       a-2:       -         -      -     0         +  
(a-1)(a-2):       +         0      -     0         +
           -----------------1------------2-------------------  
                      number line for value of a
```

As you can see from the diagram, $(a-1)(a-2)$ is a product of two negative numbers and is therefore positive when $a<1$. When $a>2$ it’s a product of two positive numbers and is again positive. Of course it’s $0$ when one of the factors is $0$, but when $a$ is between $1$ and $2$, the $a-1$ factor is positive, and the $a-2$ factor is negative, so the product is negative.

**Added.** You can use the same idea for a product of any number of linear factors. For the inequality $(a-1)(a-2)(a-4)<0$ the diagram becomes:

```
       a-1:       -         0  +  +       +       +  +
       a-2:       -         -  -  0       +       +  +
       a-4:       -         -  -  -       -       0  +
(a-1)(a-2):       -         0  +  0       -       0  +  
           -----------------1-----2---------------4----  
                      number line for value of a
```

Now all three factors are negative when $a<1$, so their product is negative. When $a$ is between $1$ and $2$, two of them are negative and the third is positive, so their product is positive. When $a$ is between $2$ and $4$, only one factor is negative, so their producis negative. Finally, when $a>4$ all three factors are positive, and so is their product. Thus, the solution set is the union of two intervals: $(-\infty,1)\cup(2,4)$.

Comment: This is a good way of looking at it.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: @Aditya: I’ve added the corresponding diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: First solve $a^2-3a+2=0$ which gives $a=1$ and $a=2$
Step 2: Put the solutions on a number line. Now you have three regions. For each region, pick a number and put that in the inequality. So for example, pick $a=-10$ which gives you a positive outcome. Pick $a=1.5$ which gives you a negative outcome. Pick $a=10$ which gives you a positive outcome. So the signs on the numberline are$+ , - , +$ Step 3: Since the inequality is $<0$, it follows that $a$ needs to be between $1$ and $2$

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your first line of working is spurious: $a<1$;$a<2$ which other answers have shown does not hold. I think solving this graphically would be the best way to see it. You have correctly factorised to $(a-1)(a-2) = 0$ so you can find the zeroes of the function i.e. the x-intercepts of the parabola.

Answer (score 0):

> **Theorem.** For all real numbers $x$ and $y$, we have $xy < 0$ iff ($x<0$ and $y>0$) OR ($x>0$ and $y<0$).

So $(a−1)(a−2)<0$ iff

- $a-1<0$ and $a-2>0$, or
- $a-1>0$ and $a-2<0$.

So $(a−1)(a−2)<0$ iff

- $a<1$ and $a>2$, or
- $a>1$ and $a<2$.

So $(a−1)(a−2)<0$ iff

- $a>1$ and $a<2$.

Comment: Please can you put aside the theorem for a while and tell me the thinking process behind it?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, ask yourself: under what circumstances is a product of two real numbers going to be negative? Obviously, the product is going to be negative iff one of those numbers is negative and the other is positive.

Answer (score 0):

$(a−1)(a−2)<0$

$\implies \{a<1$ and $a>2\}$ or $\{a>1$ and $a<2\}$

You can see that there is no real number satisfing $\{a<1$ and $a>2\}$, so the answer is $1<a<2$.

Comment: How did you deduce the first outcome?

Comment: It comes from $a^2 - 3a + 2 = (a-1)(a-2) < 0$

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, using the theorem I state in my answer :)

Comment: oh, I misunderstand your question. Please refer goblin's answer, which is more comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you are wrong as far as your hypothesis, which should be (-inf,2). Anyway the two parenthesis cannot be both less than 0. Find out why is this you have k*l that k,l< 0 that means k*l>0. Then as far as 2>1 this means that when (a-1)<0=>a<1=>(a-2)<0 so a must be in (1,2)